# Model binding in nested resources in Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I am building a RESTful api in Laravel, with my front end app in Angular.

I have a number of models / controllers and routes. I am struggling to get to grips with creating restful route for nested resources.

For example, my route to show a list of clients is simple:

```
 Route::resource('clients', 'ClientsController');
```

A client can have many campaigns:

```
class Client extends Model
{

    public function campaigns()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Campaign');
    }

}
```

I do not need a route to show all campaigns, but I do need a route to show all campaigns based on a client.

```
Route::resource('clients.campaigns', 'CampaignsController');
```

My intention was for the endpoint requested by the Angular app to be:

```
myapp/api/clients/6/campaigns
```

Where '6' is the client ID. This would return a list of campaigns that belong to client with id 6.

In my index method, I am trying to use implicit model binding to get this client Id, but I always get an empty result set:

```
class CampaignsController extends ApiController
{

    public function index(Client $client)
    {
        $campaigns = Campaign::where('client_id', $client->id)->get();
        if (!count($campaigns)) {
            Log::warning('Campaigns list is empty');
            return $this->respondNotFound('No Campaigns Found');
        }

        try {
            return $this->respond([
                'data' => $this->campaignTransformer->transformCollection($campaigns->all())
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Logging::logException($e, 'API error showing campaigns list');
            return $this->respondInternalError('An internal error occurred');
        }
    }

}
```

Clearly my route isn't binding a client - a var_dump on $client shows this.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this issue - Laravel was injecting the client_id for me.

Therefore index method becomes:

```
public function index($client_id)
{
    $campaigns = Campaign::where('client_id', $client_id)->get();
}
```

Comment: I'm facing same issue... Why I must use `$client_id` instead of `Client $client`, I would like model binding :D

Comment: @Zalo you want implicit model binding - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: @DJC Yes, but there is no info about Model binding in Resource Controller.